PGF of hypergeometric distribution
The hypergeometric distribution is given by the law: $$P(x)= \frac{\binom{M}{x} \binom{\theta - M}{n - x}}{\binom{\theta}{n}}, \theta, M, n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}, M\leq\theta, n\leq\theta, x\in\{\max(0, M+n- \theta), \min(M, n)\}$$
The probability generating function for the hypergeometric distribution has the form: $$G(z) = {}_2F_{1}[-n,-M,-\theta,1-z] = 1 + \frac{nM}{-\theta}\frac{(1-z)}{1!}+\frac{n(-n+1)M(-M+1)}{-\theta(-\theta+1)}\frac{(1-z)^{2}}{2!}+\ldots$$
In almost all sources it is presented as the hypergeometric function presented above and its corresponding series, but I could not find anywhere a proof of this formula and how it is obtained based on the definition of the probability generating function: $G(z) = Mz^{\xi}$, where the random variable $\xi$ has a hypergeometric distribution. Is it possible to somehow obtain it by definition?

Let me switch the symbols to a more frequently used ones, $ (\theta, n, M) \to (N, n, K) $, so that
$$ \mathbf{P}(\xi = k) = \frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}} $$
Then we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[z^{\xi}]
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k \mathbf{P}(\xi = k)
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k \frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( [w]^k (1 + zw)^K \right) \left( [w]^{n-k} (1 + w)^{N-K} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} [w]^n(1 + zw)^K (1 + w)^{N-K} \\
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{(1 + zw)^K (1 + w)^{N-K}}{w^{n+1}} \, \mathrm{d}w,
\end{align*}
where $\gamma$ is any simple closed curve in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ winding $0$ in counter-clockwise direction. Now assume $\gamma$ is sufficiently close to $w = 0$ and substitute $v = \frac{w}{w+1}$. This amounts to writing $w = \frac{v}{1-v}$. Moreover, $\gamma$ is mapped to another simple closed curve winding $0$ in CCW direction. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[z^{\xi}]
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{(1-(1-z)v)^K}{v^{n+1}(1-v)^{N+1-n}} \, \mathrm{d}v.
\end{align*}
Now by invoking the formula $\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{m+k}{k} z^k$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[z^{\xi}]
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{(1-(1-z)v)^K}{v^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(N-n+k)!}{k!(N-n)!}v^k \, \mathrm{d}v \\
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(N-n+k)!}{k!(N-n)!} [v^{n-k}] (1-(1-z)v)^K \\
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(N-n+k)!}{k!(N-n)!} (-1)^{n-k} \binom{K}{n-k} (1-z)^{n-k} \\
&= \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{j} \frac{(N-j)!}{(n-j)!(N-n)!} \binom{K}{j} (1-z)^{j} \tag{$j=n-k$} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^{j} \frac{n!(N-j)!K!}{N!(n-j)!j!(K-j)!} (1-z)^{j}.
\end{align*}
Finally, note that
$$ \frac{n!}{(n-j)!} = n(n-1)\cdots(n-j+1) = (-1)^j (-n)_j, $$
where $(x)_j = \frac{\Gamma(x+j)}{\Gamma(x)}$ is the Pochhammer symbol. Then the above sum simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[z^{\xi}]
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{(-n)_j (-K)_j}{(-N)_j} \frac{(1-z)^{j}}{j!}
= {}_2 F_{1}(-n, -K; -N; 1-z).
\end{align*}

Thank you so much! You helped me a lot!
